# Can't stop passenger standalone, kill operation not permitted

Tags: rvm, passenger

I've run `passenger stop -p 80` and this is the response:

```
/home/staging/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/daemon_controller-1.1.4/lib/daemon_controller.rb:445:in `kill': Operation not permitted (Errno::EPERM)
```

The same command with sudo just says no such command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I'm using rvm, the passenger command only exists for my deploy user called staging, and not sudo (root). RVM has it's own sudo command though.

```
rvmsudo passenger stop -p 80
```